# How do I notify another goroutine to stop?

Tags: go

I have 2 goroutines, `g` is used to detect the condition when `f` should stop, `f` checks whether it should stop in each iteration before doing the actual processing. In other languages such as Java, I would use a thread-safe shared variable, like the following code:

```
func g(stop *bool) {
  for {
    if check_condition() {
      *stop = true
      return
    }
  }
}

func f(stop *bool) {
  for {
    if *stop {
      return
    }
    do_something()
  }
}

func main() {
  var stop = false
  go g(&stop)
  go f(&stop)
  ...
}
```

I know the code above is not safe, but if I use channel to send stop from `g` to `f`, `f` would be blocked on reading from the channel, this is what I want to avoid. What is the safe and idiomatic way of doing this in Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use channel close to notify other goroutines of a condition. Use select with a default clause to avoid blocking when checking for the condition.

```
func g(stop chan struct{}) {
    for {
        if check_condition() {
            close(stop)
            return
        }
    }
}

func f(stop chan struct{}) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            return
        default:
            do_something()
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var stop = make(chan struct{})
    go g(stop)
    go f(stop)
}
```

It also works to send a value to a channel with capacity greater than zero, but closing the channel extends to supporting multiple goroutines.

Answer (score 1):

The way is to use a select statement with a default clause (see [this example](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations)).

So `f` would look something like:

```
func f(stop chan bool) {
  select {
    case s := <- stop:
      if s {
        return
      }
    default:
      do_something()
  }
}
```

Comment: That would block `f` before `g` sends stop.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: No it does not block. It is the canonical way to do what you want. Push true into the stop channel when you want f to stop `doing_something`.